# pass parameters through stripe checkout session

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, stripe-payments, ejs

I have this on my on my `payments.ejs`,

```
    <head>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
</head>
<div class="box">
    <!-- <form action="/paymentsPage" method="POST"> -->
    <div class="input-container">       
        <input type="text" name="code" id="code" required/>
        <label>Code</label>
    </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="checkout-button">submit</button>
<!-- </form> -->
</div>


<!-- a312b7a0338d -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
    var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51J0C0JFtPC3YhhMO5SoK5wnP01gK8apNhjq6TD21T3VHH6a7vet3Cl4PplWk7mkTPtJQwJVpt6ILjJMsnKPQOwCV00RDCU0c9j");
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById("checkout-button");

   
    checkoutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var code = document.getElementById("code").value
        console.log(code)
      fetch("/create-checkout-session", {
        method: "POST",
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (session) {
          return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id, code: code });
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          // If redirectToCheckout fails due to a browser or network
          // error, you should display the localized error message to your
          // customer using error.message.
          if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    });
  </script>
```

I want to pass `code` to the backend. So I tried to pass it though as a parameter of `stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id, code: code })` but it didn't work. How do I pass `code` to the backend

backend code:

```
    app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {

    var userCode = req.body.code;
    console.log("51: " + userCode)

    var clientName = "gianluca"

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'cad',
          product_data: {
            name: "Invoice for " + clientName,
            images: ['https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png'],
          },
          unit_amount: 2000,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success.html`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/cancel.html`,
  });

  res.json({ id: session.id });
   
});
```

what is the steps to passing the parameter to the backend? Thanks :)

Comment: you have to modify also the backend part to receive the parameter. Show the relevant code on the backend part. It is feasible anyway

Comment: @LelioFaieta just showed backend :)

Answer (score -1):

It worked when I did this:

```
fetch("/create-checkout-session", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
        code: code
        }),
  })
```

for future reference of anyone who looks at this :)